# Scaling out SignalR with SQL Server - is it possible to add messages from an outside service?

Tags: c#, sql-server, signalr, scalability

I am using SQL Server as a backplane for scaling out my SignalR.
In my scenario there are some services which run on other servers and I need to integrate their working status into my SignalR hub.

I tried as a test running a simple Console application with the SQL server scaleout and publish a message like this:

```
        var config = new SqlScaleoutConfiguration(connectionString);
        GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        var messageBus = new SqlMessageBus(GlobalHost.DependencyResolver, config);
        var message = new Message("TransactionHub", "RegisterClient","{userId:1}");
        messageBus.Publish(message);
```

Can I use the SQLScaleout like this somehow?

If not, is there some other way to do what I am trying to do?

**Edit:**

I've done as halter73 suggested and it works ok, you have to notice that if you activate a client side function, the parameter you send has to match, ie if the object is "Namespace.ClassName" then you should send an object of the same type exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using `GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext` instead of publishing to the bus directly. Your code would look something like this:

```cs
var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TransactionHub>();
context.Clients.All.registerClient(new { userId = 1 });
```

Comment: Should it be GetHubContext instead of GetConnectionContext ? the latter causes an error with Clients property...

Comment: That was a typo. It definitely should be GetHubContext.